# Data transfer between online Mysql and SQL Server databases

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, synchronization

I want to transfer data between Mysql and SQL Server databases, but both are hosted online.

I tried to do this thing using odbc, but it did not work. What is the best solution for this task? ODBC/web services/some other method? Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: a one off transfer, or ongoing?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the Microsoft Sync Framework, it's very flexible and can deal with different databases.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default

Answer (score 0):

There are some database syncing tools already existed. One great tool I can recommend is the **[Navicat Premium](http://www.navicat.com/)**. This tool supports different servers.

Answer (score -1):

Create your own  data sync app. It's not  so hard to create.

Comment: Disagree - it's like threading, looks deceptively simple until you try it.

Comment: Why do you want to  add threading here.. Question is simple. He need data transfer app.  we could achieve by creating  app. only we need source , destination  connection strings and field mappings.